# Spring MVC file upload - Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, file-upload, illegalstateexception

So I'm a newbie to Spring and I'm trying to get file upload working for my project (I'm using Spring Tool Suite btw.) and when submitting a form all I'm getting is:

> HTTP Status 500 - Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

Stack trace from browser:

```
type Exception report

message Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2643)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1083)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 logs.
```

This is the form tag in jsp:

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post"
            action="newArtist.html" modelAttribute="artist" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Input part:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="photo">Artist photo:</label>
        <form:input type="file" id="photo" path="photo"></form:input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Photo is stored in this field in Artist object:

```
@Lob
private byte[] photo;
```

Controller mapping methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newArtist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddArtistForm(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("artist", new Artist());
    return "newArtist";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/newArtist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addArtist(@ModelAttribute("artist") @Valid Artist artist, BindingResult result,
        @RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile photo) throws IOException
{   
    if (result.hasErrors())
        return "newArtist";

    if(photo.getBytes() != null)
        artist.setPhoto(photo.getBytes());

    artistService.addArtist(artist);

    return "redirect:artists.html";
}
```

Multipart resolver configuration in servlet-context.xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>
```

Filters in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Dependencies:

```
<!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also imported Tomcat's config file context.xml to META-INF/context.xml and edited Context tag like so:

```
<Context allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
```

Nothing seems to be working, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24267170/755401

Comment: I answered in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63111462/4020329) and my problem was solved

Answer (score 9):

Actually you don't need any filter on the web.xml in order to upload your multipart file with Spring MVC. I've the same configuration in my project and it worked (${spring.version} = 4.3.4.RELEASE):

POM

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

HTML

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadAction">
        <table>
            <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Spring context

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>
```

Spring controller

```
@PostMapping("/uploadAction")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        File out = new File("outputfile.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(out);

            // Writes bytes from the specified byte array to this file output stream 
            fos.write(file.getBytes());
            System.out.println("Upload and writing output file ok");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found" + e);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception while writing file " + ioe);
        } finally {
            // close the streams using close method
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Error while closing stream: " + ioe);
            }

            //storageService.store(file);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

None of the answers address the issue properly. As per [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html), on the configuration of `allowCasualMultipartParsing`:

> Set to true if Tomcat should automatically parse multipart/form-data request bodies when HttpServletRequest.getPart* or HttpServletRequest.getParameter* is called, even when the target servlet isn't marked with the @MultipartConfig annotation (See Servlet Specification 3.0, Section 3.2 for details). **Note that any setting other than false causes Tomcat to behave in a way that is not technically spec-compliant**. The default is false.

So, what's the compliant way? Reading the official [JEE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glrbb.html) gives a hint. If you want to use a spec-compliant way with Servlet 3 or newer, your servlet must have a `MultipartConfig`. You have three choices, depending on how you configure your servlet:

- With programmatic configuration: `context.addServlet(name, servlet).setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("your_path")`.
- With annotations, annotate the servlet's class with `@javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig`.
- With XML configuration, add this to the `WEB-INF/web.xml` descriptor, in the section of your servlet:

  ```
  <multipart-config>
       <location>/tmp</location>
       <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
       <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
       <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
  </multipart-config>
  ```

Answer (score 8):

For those who get the same exception for `PUT` method handlers: use `POST` instead. `PUT` is incompatible with the multi-part.

More details can be found in the [respective answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373912/spring-mvc-framework-multipartresolver-with-put-method)

Answer (score 4):

It is straight forward from the exception that no multi-part configuration is found. Though you have provided ***multipartResolver*** bean.

The problem is that while specifying the MultipartFilter before the Spring Security filter, It tries to get the ***multipartResolver*** bean but can't find it. Because it expect the bean name/id as ***filterMultipartResolver*** instead of ***multipartResolver***.

Do yourself a favor. Please change the bean configuration like following -

```
<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: For reference, I used it as an alias:

`<bean id="multipartResolver" name="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>` 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Add In your config file as:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver CanBeAnyName() { 
//configuration

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar, but what i did is just send a file without mapping it with any attribute in my model, in your case i would modify this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="photo">Artist photo:</label>
        <input type="file" id="photo" name="file"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newArtist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addArtist(@ModelAttribute("artist") @Valid Artist artist, BindingResult result,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException
//Here read the file and store the bytes into your photo attribute
...
```

Comment: Unfortunetely it didn't work, still the same error occurs.

Comment: @kbijoch just for test purposes, remove the Valid from your controller. All your configuration looks right, i have the same and is working

Comment: Still no success, but thanks for helping. Does the file name matter?

Comment: I dont think so, but you could try with one small less than 1mb and named test.log or something like that. Is weird i have the same code, let me check again

Comment: I tried some files with different extensions, still the same issue. Could be environment-related?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in a Spring Boot application, this exceptions occur several times:

- org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is
- java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field multipartFile exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field multipartFile exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.

Get rid of the tomcat exception with this, with copy catting from http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-file-upload-example/

Tomcat large file upload connection reset. Need to let {@link #containerCustomizer()} work properly, other wise exception will occur several times, RequestMapping for uploadError will fail.

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbedded() {

    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

    tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {
        if ((connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>)) {
            //-1 means unlimited
            ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1);
        }
    });

    return tomcat;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using J2EE and not spring framework and still facing issue

what you can try is adding  `@MultipartConfig` annotation on servlet and add  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside form tag

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Tomcat 8. 
Configure the following in Tomcat's conf/context.xml

- Add allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" attribute to context node
- Add <Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" /> inside context node