# Error while uploading image with form using Angular Js and Spring Mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, image-upload

I have succeeded in uploading image into Database using AngularJS and Spring Mvc.But now I need to add form feilds and submit it simultaneously.
Please do help me.Here is my code.

**controller.js**

```
scope.product = {};
scope.addProduct=function(product){
var formData=new FormData();
formData.append("file",file.files[0]);
formData.append("product",angular.toJson(product));
http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/name/addProduct',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
    data: formData,
        })
       .success(function(data, status) {                       
            alert("Success ... " + status);
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            alert("Error ... " + status);
        });
        };
```

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct",consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Product addProduct(Product product,
        @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
        HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
                throws IOException, SerialException, SQLException{

    byte[] mediaBytes = file.getBytes();
    product.setImage(mediaBytes);
    Product product2 = adminService.addProduct(product);
    return product2;
}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {

@Id
@Column(name="productId")
private Integer productId;

@Column(name="itemName")
private String itemName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="categoryId",insertable=true, updatable=true,
        nullable=false)
//@JsonManagedReference
private Category categoryId;

@Column(name="image",columnDefinition="mediumblob")
private byte[] image;

@Transient
private String statusMessage;

@Transient
private Long CategoryValue; 
//getters and setters
}
```

**addItem.html**

```
<form name="myForm" role="form" class="addItem" autocomplete="off"
id="addItem" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="productId" ng-model="product.productId" placeholder="Product Id" ng-minlength="4" maxlength="4" required />

<input class="form-control" name="itemName" type="text" ng-model="product.itemName" required />

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="categoryValue" ng-model="product.categoryValue" required />

<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"
value="Submit" data-ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
                            ng-   click="myForm.$invalid=true;addProduct(product)" /> 
            </form>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
ServletInvocableHandlerMethod:164 - Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'com.tta.abcd.model.Product'
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'properties' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.RequestPartServletServerHttpRequest.<init>(RequestPartServletServerHttpRequest.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:126)
```

**update**

After removing @RequestPart("properties") am getting product data as null in controller.

I have posted here after trying many ways.
Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please refer the below link for the resolution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922973/spring-mvc-file-upload-unable-to-process-parts-as-no-multi-part-configuration

Comment: i have reffered it.Its not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my issue.Am posting changes i have made,If incase anyone needs it.

**Controller.js**

```
formData.append("file",file.files[0]);
formData.append("product",new Blob([JSON.stringify(product)],{type: "application/json"}));
```

**Controller.java**

```
public Product addProduct(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestPart("product")Product product,
        HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException, SerialException, SQLException{

    byte[] mediaBytes = file.getBytes();
    product.setImage(mediaBytes);
    Product product2 = adminService.addProduct(product);
    return product;
}
```

After these changes,My code worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the below bean id in your spring context file.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"><property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/></bean>
```

And if you are using maven, add the dependencies as well.

```
<!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons IO -->
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yes its already present,i think the problem is sending from angular side

Comment: Please try with the below one...
    `var fd = new FormData();`
    `fd.append("files", $scope.file);`

Answer (score 1):

Your variable names don't add upp.

In angular

```
formData.append("product",angular.toJson(product))
```

but in spring you've called it

```
@RequestPart("properties") Product product
```

Could that be the problem?

Comment: Now i have changed code.control is hitting to spring.But am getting product values as null after removing  @RequestPart("properties") .

Answer (score 1):

```
 formData.append("file",file.files[0]);
 formData.append("user",new Blob([JSON.stringify(user)],{type: "application/json"}));
                http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/projectName/url',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},//to set boundary value by default
                    data: formData,
                        })
```