# multipart upload is failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resteasy

I'm trying to upgrade my Spring Boot version from 1.2.6 to 2.3.7 and also Spring version from 4.1.1 to 5.2.12 and RESTEasy from 3.1.1 to 3.6.2, but I'm geting below exception while trying to upload file using RESTEasy multipart.

```
10 Feb 2021 18:13:20.177 [http-nio-18080-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]- Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided] with root cause  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2829) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2797) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:87) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1178) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1012) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at com.xactly.logging.filter.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:87) ~[commons-logging-logback-1.2.3-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring MVC file upload - Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922973/spring-mvc-file-upload-unable-to-process-parts-as-no-multi-part-configuration)

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your application and the beans that you have defined? Spring Boot should auto-configure the multi-part configuration unless you have defined a `CommonsMultipartResolver` bean or set `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:
need to add

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multi(){
     CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;
}
```

and commons-fileupload   dependency