# Spring MVC file upload: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

Tags: java, spring-mvc, upload

I'm trying to upload a file using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf but I'm getting an exception saying that multi-part configuration has not been provided.

This is my Thymeleaf Form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/settings/profile}"
    th:object="${profileSettingsForm}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="profilePicture">Picture</label> <input type="file"
            th:field="*{profilePicture}" id="profilePicture" name="profilePicture">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label> <input type="text"
            th:field="*{username}" class="form-control" id="username"
            placeholder="Type your new username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="biography">Biography</label>
        <textarea th:field="*{biography}" class="form-control" id="biography"
            rows="3" placeholder="Type your new biography"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my form binding class:

```
public class ProfileSettingsForm {

    private static final String NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE = "{notBlank.message}";

    private MultipartFile profilePicture;

    @NotBlank(message = ProfileSettingsForm.NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = ProfileSettingsForm.NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE)
    private String biography;

    public ProfileSettingsForm() {

    }

    public ProfileSettingsForm(String username, String biography) {
        this.username = username;
        this.biography = biography;
    }

    // Getters and setters

}
```

Also, I have configured the Multipart resolver as the documentation says in my `WebMvcConfig.java` like this:

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000);
    return resolver;
}
```

Why is the upload form not working even when I have set up my MultiPartResolver? Am I missing something?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24267170/755401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it. For anyone who is having the same issue, the solution was to register the multipart configuration in my `WebAbbInitializer.java`, adding this custom method:

```
private static final String LOCATION = "C:/temp/"; // Temporary location where files will be stored

private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5242880; // 5MB : Max file size.
                                                   // Beyond that size spring will throw exception.
private static final long MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 20971520; // 20MB : Total request size containing Multi part.
private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0; // Size threshold after which files will be written to disk
private MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement() {

MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(
            LOCATION, MAX_FILE_SIZE, MAX_REQUEST_SIZE, FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
    return multipartConfigElement;
}
```

Finally, register it in the same file like this:

```
@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
}
```

You can read more about [here.](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-file-upload-example-using-multipartconfigelement/)

Answer (score 2):

It is straight forward from the exception that no multi-part configuration is found. Though you have provided multipartResolver bean.

The problem is that while specifying the ***MultipartFilter*** before the Spring Security filter, It tries to get the ***multipartResolver*** bean but can't find it. Because it expect the bean name/id as ***filterMultipartResolver*** instead of ***multipartResolver***.

Do yourself a favor. Please change the bean configuration like following -

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000);
    return resolver;
}
```

Or

```
@Bean(name = "filterMultipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000);
    return resolver;
}
```